# Integrate aspectj-maven-plugin in bazel

Tags: aspectj, bazel

Ive got a blocker, I am not able to integrate the plugin above in bazel. I have been investigating,how to deal with it (threads, chatGpt). But I found repositories and information outdated. Exactly, I am trying how to integrate the filling plugin. I tried in maven, it works. But im not able to do this in bazel. Any information? help?

```
   <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.14.0</version>
         <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
             <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
             <aspectLibraries>
                 <aspectLibrary>
                     <groupId>software.amazon.lambda</groupId>
                     <artifactId>powertools-tracing</artifactId>
                 </aspectLibrary>
                 <aspectLibrary>
                     <groupId>software.amazon.lambda</groupId>
                     <artifactId>powertools-logging</artifactId>
                 </aspectLibrary>
                 <aspectLibrary>
                     <groupId>software.amazon.lambda</groupId>
                     <artifactId>powertools-metrics</artifactId>
                 </aspectLibrary>
             </aspectLibraries>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Get some information about my block. I have been trying to find a solution in bazel, but nothing works

Comment: Why would you think that a plugin for build tool A (Maven) should be compatible with build tool B (Bazel)? If you like Bazel so much and know how to use it, I am sure it will not be so super difficult to write your own plugin or some other wrapper for the Aspectj compiler (ajc).

Comment: _"I have been trying to find a solution in bazel, but nothing works."_ Why don't you show what you tried? Are you expecting someone else to do the whole work for you? Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.